# Identity from unit circle onto itself cannot be extended to a continuous function from unit disk onto unit circle

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $C_r$ be the circle $x^2+y^2=r^2$ and $D$ the unit disk $x^2+y^2\leq 1$. Show that the identity from $C_1$ onto itself cannot be extended to a continuous function from $D$ onto $C_1$. $Hint$: Take polar coordinates $(r(p),\theta(p))$ for any point $p\in D$, so $r\circ g\equiv 1$. Let $(r,\phi)$ be the coordinates of points in $D$, with $0\leq\phi<2\pi$. Show that $\theta(g(r,\phi))$ can be defined to be continuous (not necessarily with values in [0,2$\pi$)) as a function of $\phi$ for $r>0$. Let $h(r):=\displaystyle\lim_{\phi\rightarrow 2\pi}\theta(g(r,\phi))-\theta(g(r,0))$. Show that $h$ is continuous as a function of $r$, must always be a multiple of $2\pi$, but has different values at $r=0$ and $r=1$.

My efforts:

Use the metric topology. The metric is just $d((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))=\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1+y_2)^2}$. We will use polar coordinate. The metric can be expressed with polar coordinates: $d((r_1,\phi_1),(r_2,\phi_2))=\sqrt{r_1^2+r_2^2-2r_1r_2cos(\phi_1-\phi_2)}$.

Assume that the identity from $C_1$ onto itself cannot be extended to a continuous function $g$ from $D$ onto $C_1$. We will derive a contradiction.

The point $g(r,\phi)$ is on the unit circle and thus has polar coordinates $r(g(r,\phi))$ and $\theta(g(r,\phi))$. Of course $r(g(r,\phi))=1$. Since $g$ is continuous, for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $d(g(r_1,\phi_1),g(r_2,\phi_2))=\sqrt{2-2cos(\theta(g(r_1,\phi_1))-\theta(g(r_2,\phi_2)))}<\epsilon$ if $\sqrt{r_1^2+r_2^2-2r_1r_2cos(\phi_1-\phi_2)}<\delta$. This also holds for $r_1=r_2=r>0$. Thus for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $d(g(r,\phi_1),g(r,\phi_2))=\sqrt{2-2cos(\theta(g(r,\phi_1))-\theta(g(r,\phi_2)))}<\epsilon$ if $r\sqrt{2-2cos(\phi_1-\phi_2)}<\delta$. We just require $0\leq\theta(g(r,\phi))<2\pi$. Then for any $\epsilon^*>0$, there exists $\delta^*>0$, such that $|\phi_1-\phi_2|<\delta^*\Rightarrow r\sqrt{2-2cos(\phi_1-\phi_2)}<\delta$ $\Rightarrow\sqrt{2-2cos(\theta(g(r,\phi_1))-\theta(g(r,\phi_2)))}<\epsilon\Rightarrow|\theta(g(r,\phi_1))-\theta(g(r,\phi_2))|<\epsilon^*$. Thus $\theta(g(r,\phi))$ is continuous as a function of $\phi$ for $r>0$.

Let $h(r):=\displaystyle \lim_{\phi\rightarrow 2\pi}\theta(g(r,\phi))-\theta(g(r,0))$. Since $g$ is continuous, for any $\epsilon^*>0$, there exists $\delta>0$, such that $|r_1-r_2|=\sqrt{r_1^2+r_2^2-2r_1r_2cos(0-0)}=\displaystyle\lim_{\phi\rightarrow 2\pi}\sqrt{r_1^2+r_2^2-2r_1r_2cos(\phi-\phi)}<\delta$ $\Rightarrow\sqrt{2-2cos(\theta(g(r_1,0))-\theta(g(r_2,0)))}<\epsilon/2$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{\phi\rightarrow 2\pi}\sqrt{2-2cos(\theta(g(r_1,\phi))-\theta(g(r_2,\phi)))}<\epsilon/2$ $\Rightarrow|\theta(g(r_1,0))-\theta(g(r_2,0))|<\epsilon^*/2$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{\phi\rightarrow 2\pi}|\theta(g(r_1,\phi))-\theta(g(r_2,))|<\epsilon^*/2\Rightarrow|h(r_1)-h(r_2)|<\epsilon^*$. Thus $h$ is continuous as a function of $r$.

When $\phi\rightarrow 2\pi$, $(r,\phi)\rightarrow(r,0)$ for any $r$. Due to the continuity of $g$, $\displaystyle\lim_{\phi\rightarrow 2\pi}\sqrt{2-2cos(\theta(g(r,\phi))-\theta(g(r,0)))}=\sqrt{2-2cos(h(r))}=0$. Thus $h$ must always be a multiple of $2\pi$.

Then I don't know how to proceed for $h(1)$.

Comment: I have only seen this proved using algebraic topology (as per the answer below).

Comment: Note that $g(1,\phi)=e^{i\phi}$ by construction, so that $\theta \circ g(1,\phi)=\phi$ and thus $h(1)=2\pi$. As $g(0,\phi)$ is constant, $h(0)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

If $Id\colon S^1 \rightarrow S^1$ is extended to a continuous function $F\colon D^2 \rightarrow S^1$, the we have the composition $S^1 \xrightarrow{i} D^2 \xrightarrow{F} S^1$ equal to the identity $Id$. This induces a composition of homomorphisms between fundamental groups, that is, $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ which must be the identity homomorphism because fundamental group is a functor. But this cannot happen.

Comment: It seems @Junk Warrior doesn't have access to the fundamental group and methods of algebraic topology

Answer (score 0):

There's a theorem that there cannot exist a retraction from the unit disk onto the unit circle.

The  proof involves a connectivity argument.

One removes a couple of points $a,b$ from $S^1$, leaving two disconnected arcs.   One then looks at the preimages of $a$ and $b$ under the retraction.  When the dust clears, it becomes possible to construct a continuous function which takes a connected set to this disconnected one.

The no retraction theorem can be used to prove the Brouwer Fixed Point Theorem.

Comment: The Brouwer Fixed Point Theorem can answer the Q. Suppose $f:D\to S^1$ is continuous with $f|_{S^1}=id_{S^1}.$ The function $g(p)=-f(p)$ must have a fixed point $p_0\in D,$ and $p_0\not \in S^1.$ But then $f(p_0)=-g(p_0)=-p_0\not\in S^1,$ a contradiction.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet nice.  i expected as much.